# Prioritizing I/O for media playback

Tags: media-server, file-server

I have noticed that I cannot possibly play back a 1080p video from XBMC while something else is going on, e.g. a Samba transfer.

Is there a simple way to set up my Raspberry Pi server (or just XBMC) to prioritize I/O for video playback or generally everything XBMC?

I read about `ionice`, but it seems like a makeshift temporary solution.

I'm using `systemd`, so integrating the solution would be a nice plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in `IOSchedulingPriority` and to some extend  `IOSchedulingClass` and `Nice` `systemd` parameters. First one sets ionice priority for your service (`0` is the highest, `7` is the lowest), second sets scheduling class -you can choose from `none`, `realtime`, `best-effort` or `idle` (`realtime` may be interesting for you if you want to elevate the priority). `Nice` parameter just sets process nice level but it may also be helpful.

Comment: It works, a bit, but doesn't cut it on an rPi. The USB controller is just too slow :-(